# setting azure apim policy based on hostname

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, host, policy

Hi below is my azure apim policy

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="dynamic-realm" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-kc-realm-id", ""))" />
        <set-variable name="dynamic-host" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-kc-host", ""))" />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="@($"https://{(string)context.Variables["dynamic-host"]}/realms/{(string)context.Variables["dynamic-realm"]}/.well-known/openid-configuration")" />
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Now i need to set policy like below

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="dynamic-realm" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-kc-realm-id", ""))" />
        <set-variable name="dynamic-host" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-kc-host", ""))" />
 
> if dynamic-host has portal.a.ai choose keycloakd.a.com
> 
> else if dynamic-host has dev.b.ai choose keycloakd.b.ai
> 
> else return 404
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="@($"https://{(string)context.Variables["dynamic-host"]}/realms/{(string)context.Variables["dynamic-realm"]}/.well-known/openid-configuration")" />
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Basically i want to set a inbound policy to route the authentication to the respective url based on the hot name. Kindly guide as how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i have modified your policy a bit to include  block that checks value of dynamic-host and sets the keycloak-url respectively. so for instance if the dynamic-host is portal.a.ai then it sets keycloak-url to keycloakd.a.com and incase this condition is not met it wil return 404 response..

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="dynamic-realm" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-kc-realm-id", ""))" />
        <set-variable name="dynamic-host" value="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-kc-host", ""))" />

        <choose>
            <when condition="@((string)context.Variables["dynamic-host"] == "portal.a.ai")">
                <set-variable name="keycloak-url" value="keycloakd.a.com" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@((string)context.Variables["dynamic-host"] == "dev.b.ai")">
                <set-variable name="keycloak-url" value="keycloakd.b.ai" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response response-variable-name="response" status-code="404" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>

        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
            <openid-config url="@($"https://{(string)context.Variables["keycloak-url"]}/realms/{(string)context.Variables["dynamic-realm"]}/.well-known/openid-configuration")" />
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

In your  element u can use keycloak-url var to construct URL for OpenID config.

hope this helps